# Keeping decimal point

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, formatting

Currently I have the following code:

```
nj_ = 0
j_ = 0
x_ = 1
nj_ = float(snum_ / (2 ** (j_ * 2)))
while nj_ > 0.4:
    nj_ = snum_ / (2 ** (j_ * 2))
    print "                         ", x_,"* sqrt(%d)" %nj_
    j_ += 1
    x_ = x_ * 2
```

And the output is as follows:
Finding an approximate root by factoring: the root is:

```
1 * sqrt(7761549)
2 * sqrt(1940387)
4 * sqrt(485096)
8 * sqrt(121274)
16 * sqrt(30318)
32 * sqrt(7579)
64 * sqrt(1894)
128 * sqrt(473)
256 * sqrt(118)
512 * sqrt(29)
1024 * sqrt(7)
2048 * sqrt(1)
4096 * sqrt(0)
```

How do I format the output so that it prints the actually numbers with decimal points instead of the rounding the numbers?

Comment: Offtopic: Giving variables meaningful names, makes code easier to understand. Also, you can replace `x_ = x_ * 2` with `x_  *= 2` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try print line:

```
print "                         ", x_,"* sqrt(%0.4f)" %nj_
```